# including makefile while using cmake

Tags: makefile, cmake

need some help with using a 3rd party makefile when building my own project.

Comment: "I tried using the following but it doesnt work..." How does it not work? What were you expecting to happen? What did happen?

Comment: You have to tell cmake how to interpret what the gmake+makefile is doing. CMake isn't just going to magically import some random strings. How would it know to do that correctly? How would it do that safely? Maybe if you provided an example of the gmake+makefile output, and what you want to do with that output?

Comment: what do you mean by "doing"? just printing to the terminal? rebuilding your 3rd party libraries with those flags? writing those flags to a file?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a way to what you want directly. CMake doesn't provide a facility to include files into its generated files. (ie: include a "`3rdparty.mk`" into a CMake generated `Makefile`.) Nor can you directly include a "generated-file-type" (ie: a Makefile) into a `CMakeLists.txt`. CMake's [ExternalProject](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/ExternalProject.html) won't let you do that either.

What you need to do is somehow "parse" the makefile that has the information that you desire. There are a myriad of ways that you can do this. For example, you could write a shell-script wrapper that would grep your makefile for what you need then construct a CMake command line with the variables you want defined, and output it or call `cmake` for you. Depending on how comfortable you are with shell (or perl, python, etc.) you might feel this is the best option.

If you know these values will never (or very rarely change), you can hard code them in to your `CMakeLists.txt` (not recommended) or into a file you can [`include()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/include.html) (better).

You could also stay in CMake-land and use CMake's [ExternalProject](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/ExternalProject.html) to help you. Using ExternalProject, you can:

1. Fetch your 3rd party libraries (download, copy, unzip, etc)
2. Patch the Makefiles of these libraries
3. Run `make` on those patched makefiles

Now, this patch that I mentioned is something that you'd have to write yourself, and keep with the source of your primary project. The content of this patch would be a new target for make that would *write a file that you could include in your `CMakeLists.txt` via `include()`*. You could start simply, and have this new make target (eg: `make output_variables`) write a list of `set()` commands to `lib_A.cmake`. After comfortable with that, you could move on to more complicated output; like writing a `lib_A-config.cmake` file that CMake's [`find_package()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/find_package.html) would understand.

Granted, the last option is probably the most complicated but it might make maintenance of your primary project easier, reducing pain in the future. You'll also gain a deeper understanding of CMake.